# Proofs around the fundamental unit

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a algebraic number field degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with only one real embedding. $c$ is called a fundamental unit of $O_K$.

> (j) Show that $c$ is uniquely determined by the requirement $c > 1$. Show that $K = \mathbb{Q}(c)$ so that the minimal polynomial of $c$ has degree $3$.

Assume $c$ is a uniquely determined unit of $O_K$.

> (i)  $c'$ and $c''$  are conjugates of $c$ and different from $c$. Hence $c'$ and $c''$ are non-real and convex conjugate of one another.

$c'=pe^{i\phi}$

$c'' =pe^{-i\phi}$

with $p \in \mathbb{R}_+$, $\phi \in \mathbb{R}$

> Show that then  $c = p^{-2}$ and that $\textrm{disc}(c) = -4 \sin^2 \phi \cdot (p^3+p^{-3} -2 \cos \phi)^2$
>
> (ii) Show that $|\textrm{disc}(c)| \leq 4(e^3+e^{-3}+6)$
>
> (iii)  Show that $$c^3 \geq  \frac{|D_K|}{4} - c^{-3} - 6 > \frac{|D_K|}{4} - 7$$ with $D_K$ denotes the discriminant of $K$.

Comment: I am trying to follow this book http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387902791 but I am at a lost.

Comment: $c$ for a fundamental unit? Seems like an odd choice of symbol to me. Even $\mu$ would be better, or better still, $u$. Much more importantly, though, does the book give any examples at all? For example, Wolfram Alpha tells me that $1 - \root 3 \of 2$ is the fundamental unit of $\mathbb Z[\root 3 \of 2]$. Its minimal polynomial is $x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x + 1$, which I also consulted Wolfram Alpha on: the other two roots of that polynomial are complex numbers with nonzero imaginary parts.

Comment: (i) Use the unit $-1$ and the fact that $1/c$ is also a unit.